# Проверка на ввод значения

Tags: c++

Пользователь вводит определенное значение, надо сделать проверку на то, чтобы он вводил только числа, без букв и других символов , то есть если пользователь вводит "-", чтобы выводило, введите значение

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

double F(double a, double b)
{
    if (tan(a + b / 3) != 0)
    {
        if (sqrt(a + tan(a + b / 3)) >= 0)
        {
            if (1 - sqrt(a + tan(a + b / 3)) != 0)
            {
                return 1 / (1 - sqrt(a + tan(a + b / 3)));
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

}

int main() 
{   
    double x, y;
    string str;
    cout << "Vvedite chislo: ";
    cin >> str;

    for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ',')
        {
            str = str.replace(i, 1, ".");
        }
    }
    double a = stod(str);
    while (a > 999999.999999 || a < -999999.999999)
    {
        cout << "Vvedite pravilnoe chislo: ";
        cin >> str;

        for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++)
        {
            if (str[i] == ',')
            {
                str = str.replace(i, 1, ".");
            }
        }
        a = stod(str);
    }

    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------\n|       x         |           a             |          y          |\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    for (x = -1.7; x <= 6.3; x += 0.5) 
    {
        y = F(x, a);
        if (y != 0)
        {
            printf("|%10f       |%17f        |%12.6f         |\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\n", x, a, y);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("|%10f       |%17f        |%12s         |\n-------------------------------------------------------------------\n", x, a, "Nevosmojno");
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Т.е. категорически нельзя вводить числа отрицательніе или числа с плавающей точкой?

Comment: нет, такие числа можно вводить

Comment: *то есть если пользователь вводит "-", чтобы выводило, введите значение*???

Comment: типо того, чтобы была какая никакая проверка, чтобы можно было вводить только какое-то нормальное значение, условно там "-123.783". чтобы не было такого, что пользователь вводит просто "-" или "б123" и программа зависала

Comment: Вводите символьную строку и проверяете её на корректность. А потом переводите в число. Алгоритм простой - если длина строки 1, то там может быть только цифра. Если больше - на первом месте может быть ил символ '-' или цифра. Дальше перебор строки - могут быть только цифры или символ '.'. И точка может быть одна.

Comment: да да, что-то типо такого, только не знаю как реализовать...

Comment: [scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) и затем fgetc (для анализа следующего символа (у вас он д.б. валидным разделителем (пробел, табуляция, ньюлайн и т.п.)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-нибудь такое не устроит?

```
double get_value()
{
    double d;
    string s;

    for(;;)
    {
        cout << "Input value: ";
        cin >> s;
        try {
            d = stod(s);
            return d;
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            cout <<"Wrong input. ";
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Как оказалось, надо пояснить применение...

Вместо

```
int main() 
{   
    double x, y;
    string str;
    cout << "Vvedite chislo: ";
    cin >> str;

    for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ',')
        {
            str = str.replace(i, 1, ".");
        }
    }
    double a = stod(str);
```

напишите

```
int main() 
{   
    double x, y;
    double a = get_value();
```

Comment: не очень понимаю, куда это нужно вставлять

Comment: Куда угодно :) — там, где надо получить число из стандартного потока ввода.

Comment: вставил перед главной функцией main, но все равно при вводе того же самого "-" выходит ошибка, можете у себя проверить

Comment: Я таки не понял - вы просто внесли функцию в код, но не вызываете ее? Скажите, что я не так вас понял...

Comment: вы правильно меня поняли...

Comment: Ну так вызовите ее... См. дополненный отввет.

Comment: спасибо вам большое

Comment: Спасибо здесь имеет форму голосования за ответ (треугольник вверх слева), большое спасибо — принятого ответа (птичка там же).